# Laplace transform of measure on complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, laplace-transform

I construct Laplace transform of measure on complex plane，i.e. $F(t)=\int_\mathbb{C}e^{-\lambda t}d\mu(\lambda), t \in \mathbb{R},\mu(\mathbb{C})=1$ and have bounded support. Suppose that $F_n(t)=\int_\mathbb{C}e^{-\lambda t}d\mu_n(\lambda)$ is well defined, and that $F_n$ converges to $F$ pointwise. I guess that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ and $F(t)=\int_\mathbb{C}e^{-\lambda t}d\mu(\lambda)$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, since Laplace transform on probability measures on $\mathbf{C}$ (with bounded support) is no more injective. For example, the uniform measure on the unit circle $\mathbf{S}_1$ and the Dirac mass at $0$ have the same Laplace transform since holomorphic like $z \mapsto e^{-tz}$ functions satisfy the mean value property. For every $t \in \mathbf{C}$, one has
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(-te^{i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta = \exp(-t \times 0).$$

Comment: Thanks,but why we can't say $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$,although Laplace transform may corresponds many probality measure，maybe there has a measure is the limit of $\mu_n$.

Comment: The sequence given by $\mu_n$ = uniform law on $\mathbb{S}_1$ if $n$ is odd, $\mu_n = \delta_0$ if $n$ is even diverges although the Laplace transform converge (they do not depend on $n$).